# forever and other packages not found

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, gruntjs

my command:

```
date && cd ~/local/lib/node_modules/forever/bin && ls -la && forever -v
```

the output

```
Sun Nov 17 14:45:48 UTC 2013
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 nobody root 4096 Nov 17 14:15 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 nobody root 4096 Nov 17 14:15 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 nobody root   60 May  9  2013 forever
-rwxr-xr-x 1 nobody root   72 May  9  2013 foreverd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 nobody root 2135 May  9  2013 monitor
>> bash: forever: command not found
```

date command is running ok;

the directory shows forever library exists;

but the next command "forever -v" returns "command not found"

same happens with node, npm, etc...

Comment: in CentOS this works fine, but not in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

`./forever -v`

Linux is not Windows.

(Though you can make it behave like Windows by doing export PATH=.:$PATH. I don't recommend that, for security reasons!)